# Concatenate two displayfor with a delimiter in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a two @Html.DisplayFor items and need to concatenate those two with a delimiter.tried it like below.

Tried like

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(string.Format("{0}{1}", model => model.RefKey,":",model => model.RefName)</td><br><br>
```

I tried it on above way.But thrown an exception.

Comment: `DisplayFor` expects a single expression. You've got two lambdas in there but neither of them is being pass to `DisplayFor` and `string.Format` returns a `string`, not an expression. I haven't tested this so I won't post it as an answer but surely that should be `@Html.DisplayFor(model => string.Format("{0}:{1}", model.RefKey, model.RefName))` or, using string interpolation, `@Html.DisplayFor(model => $"{model.RefKey}:{model.RefName}")`

Comment: @jmcilhinney When i try it on your first solution i got the following error.. ` `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.' `

Comment: @jmcilhinney When i try it your second option.. i got the error msg `Feature:'Interpolated string is not available in c# 5'`

Comment: If you're using a version of C# that was released before string interpolation was supported then you won't be able to use string interpolation. Stick to `String.Format` in that case. I'd advise you to upgrade versions if you can but that may not be possible for some old projects.

Comment: I was afraid that it may not work. In that case, you could add a read-only property to your model class that does the concatenation internally and then you can use that property in the expression. If you are using an EF entity class directly and don't want to add a property to that, you can create a dedicated view model class. The alternative would be to actually call `DisplayFor` twice - once for each property. I'll add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunatelly you cannot combine multiple properties within single `DisplayFor` method. `DisplayFor` accept expression that can be evaluated on the object and cancualate the properties.

The workaround in your case can be the additional read-only property that prepare data for you

```
public class HomeModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "Mr. {0}")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "Salutation: {0}")]
    public String FullName
    {
        get
        {
            var pInfo = GetType().GetProperty("FirstName")
                .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayFormatAttribute>();
            var format = pInfo?.DataFormatString;

            var kvp = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { format ?? "{0}", FirstName },
                { "{0}", LastName }
            };

            return string.Join(", ", kvp.Select(m => string.Format(m.Key, m.Value)));
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FullName)
```

As you can see, in the workaround above we have applied `DisplayFormat` for individual field first, and then applied `DisplayFormat` for the combined field